# OutOfBoundsException with ALS - Flink MLlib

Tags: scala, indexoutofboundsexception, recommendation-engine, apache-flink, flinkml

I'm doing a recommandation system for movies, using the MovieLens datasets available here : 
http://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/

To compute this recommandation system, I use the ML library of Flink in scala, and particulalrly the ALS algorithm (`org.apache.flink.ml.recommendation.ALS`).

I first map the ratings of the movie into a `DataSet[(Int, Int, Double)]` and then create a `trainingSet` and a `testSet` (see the code below).

My problem is that there is no bug when I'm using the `ALS.fit` function with the whole dataset (all the ratings), but if I just remove only one rating, the fit function doesn't work anymore, and I don't understand why.

Do You have any ideas? :)

**Code used :**

**Rating.scala**

```scala
case class Rating(userId: Int, movieId: Int, rating: Double)
```

**PreProcessing.scala**

```scala
object PreProcessing {

def getRatings(env : ExecutionEnvironment, ratingsPath : String): DataSet[Rating] = {
      env.readCsvFile[(Int, Int, Double)](
      ratingsPath, ignoreFirstLine = true,
      includedFields = Array(0,1,2)).map{r => new Rating(r._1, r._2, r._3)}
}
```

**Processing.scala**

```scala
object Processing {
  private val ratingsPath: String = "Path_to_ratings.csv"

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment

    val ratings: DataSet[Rating] = PreProcessing.getRatings(env, ratingsPath)

    val trainingSet : DataSet[(Int, Int, Double)] =
    ratings
     .map(r => (r.userId, r.movieId, r.rating))
     .sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING)
     .first(ratings.count().toInt)

    val als = ALS()
     .setIterations(10)
     .setNumFactors(10)
     .setBlocks(150)
     .setTemporaryPath("/tmp/tmpALS")

    val parameters = ParameterMap()
     .add(ALS.Lambda, 0.01) // After some tests, this value seems to fit the problem
     .add(ALS.Seed, 42L)

    als.fit(trainingSet, parameters)
  }
}
```

**"But if I just remove only one rating"**

```scala
val trainingSet : DataSet[(Int, Int, Double)] =
  ratings
    .map(r => (r.userId, r.movieId, r.rating))
    .sortPartition(0, Order.ASCENDING)
    .first((ratings.count()-1).toInt)
```

**The error :**

> 06/19/2015 15:00:24   CoGroup (CoGroup at org.apache.flink.ml.recommendation.ALS$.updateFactors(ALS.scala:570))(4/4) switched to FAILED
>
> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>
> at org.apache.flink.ml.recommendation.ALS$BlockRating.apply(ALS.scala:358)
>
> at org.apache.flink.ml.recommendation.ALS$$anon$111.coGroup(ALS.scala:635)
>
> at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.CoGroupDriver.run(CoGroupDriver.java:152)
>
> ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the `first` operator in combination with the `setTemporaryPath` parameter of Flink's `ALS` implementation. In order to understand the problem, let me quickly explain how the blocking ALS algorithm works.

The blocking implementation of alternating least squares first partitions the given ratings matrix user-wise and item-wise into blocks. For these blocks, routing information is calculated. This routing information says which user/item block receives which input from which item/user block, respectively. Afterwards, the ALS iteration is started.

Since Flink's underlying execution engine is a parallel streaming dataflow engine, it tries to execute as many parts of the dataflow as possible in a pipelined fashion. This requires to have all operators of the pipeline online at the same time. This has the advantage that Flink avoids to materialize intermediate results, which might be prohibitively large. The disadvantage is that the available memory has to be shared among all running operators. In the case of ALS where the size of the individual `DataSet` elements (e.g. user/item blocks) is rather large, this is not desired.

In order to solve this problem, not all operators of the implementation are executed at the same time if you have set a `temporaryPath`. The path defines where the intermediate results can be stored. Thus, if you've defined a temporary path, then `ALS` first calculates the routing information for the user blocks and writes them to disk, then it calculates the routing information for the item blocks and writes them to disk and last but not least it starts ALS iteration for which it reads the routing information from the temporary path.

The calculation of the routing information for the user and item blocks both depend on the given ratings data set. In your case when you calculate the user routing information, then it will first read the ratings data set and apply the `first` operator on it. The `first` operator returns `n`-arbitrary elements from the underlying data set. The problem right now is that Flink does not store the result of this `first` operation for the calculation of the item routing information. Instead, when you start the calculation of the item routing information, Flink will re-execute the dataflow starting from its sources. This means that it reads the ratings data set from disk and applies the `first` operator on it again. This will give you in many cases a different set of ratings compared to the result of the first `first` operation. Therefore, the generated routing information are inconsistent and `ALS` fails.

You can circumvent the problem by materializing the result of the `first` operator and use this result as the input for the `ALS` algorithm. The object `FlinkMLTools` contains a method `persist` which takes a `DataSet`, writes it to the given path and then returns a new `DataSet` which reads the just written `DataSet`. This allows you to break up the resulting dataflow graph.

```scala
val firstTrainingSet : DataSet[(Int, Int, Double)] =
  ratings
    .map(r => (r.userId, r.movieId, r.rating))
    .first((ratings.count()-1).toInt)

val trainingSet = FlinkMLTools.persist(firstTrainingSet, "/tmp/tmpALS/training")

val als = ALS()
  .setIterations(10)
  .setNumFactors(10)
  .setBlocks(150)
  .setTemporaryPath("/tmp/tmpALS/")

val parameters = ParameterMap()
  .add(ALS.Lambda, 0.01) // After some tests, this value seems to fit the problem
  .add(ALS.Seed, 42L)

als.fit(trainingSet, parameters)
```

Alternatively, you can try to leave the `temporaryPath` unset. Then all steps (routing information calculation and als iteration) are executed in a pipelined fashion. This means that both the user and item routing information calculation use the same input data set which results from the `first` operator.

The Flink community is currently working on keeping intermediate results of operators in the memory. This will allow to pin the result of the `first` operator so that it won't be calculated twice and, thus, not giving differing results due to its non-deterministic nature.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly!
Just a question: when you use `persist`, you set the path to a file. But how does `ALS` know that this persistent file is for it and not for an other part of the program (for example if we have to `persist` for an other algorithm)?

Comment: The `persist` function call triggers the execution of the data flow up to this point. As a result any file which is stored under the same path will be overwritten. The result will only be read once you trigger the subsequent part of the job. This means that you can theoretically delete or overwrite this file in the meantime. Therefore, you should try to assign unique file names in the scope of your algorithm. Alternatively, you can also create random file names which should have a low probability to collide.